# How to use threading to help parse a large file

Tags: python, multithreading, parsing

Alright, so this file is 410k lines of code. Right now I parse it in 1.4 seconds, but I need it to be faster. There are a couple weird things about this file though...

The file is structured something like this (thanks ARM): [ARM fromelf](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0477i/BABJBGBH.html)
Basically I parse all of this into a map where the key is the name of the Structure, and in this case can be duplicated due to ARM generating Warnings. The values in this case are the fields that follow.

Is there a way I can use threads to split up the task into multiple threads adding the data to the same map?

P.S. Not looking for someone to do this for me, I just provided an example of what the file structure was like so you understand I can't just process each line, but rather I process from [start:finish] based off the structure.

Per request, a sample of what I'm parsing:

```
; Structure, Table , Size 0x104 bytes, from inputfile.cpp
|Table.TableSize|                        EQU    0        ;  int
|Table.Data|                             EQU    0x4      ;  array[64] of MyClassHandle
; End of Structure Table

; Structure, Box2 , Size 0x8 bytes, from inputfile.cpp
|Box2.|                                  EQU    0        ;  anonymous
|Box2..|                                 EQU    0        ;  anonymous
|Box2...Min|                             EQU    0        ;  Point2
|Box2...Min.x|                           EQU    0        ;  short
|Box2...Min.y|                           EQU    0x2      ;  short
|Box2...Max|                             EQU    0x4      ;  Point2
|Box2...Max.x|                           EQU    0x4      ;  short
|Box2...Max.y|                           EQU    0x6      ;  short
; Warning: duplicate name (Box2..) present in (inputfile.cpp) and in (inputfile.cpp)
; please use the --qualify option
|Box2..|                                 EQU    0        ;  anonymous
|Box2...Left|                            EQU    0        ;  unsigned short
|Box2...Top|                             EQU    0x2      ;  unsigned short
|Box2...Right|                           EQU    0x4      ;  unsigned short
|Box2...Bottom|                          EQU    0x6      ;  unsigned short
; End of Structure Box2

; Structure, MyClassHandle , Size 0x4 bytes, from inputfile.cpp
|MyClassHandle.Handle|                   EQU    0        ;  pointer to MyClass
; End of Structure MyClassHandle

; Structure, Point2 , Size 0x4 bytes, from defects.cpp
|Point2.x|                               EQU    0        ;  short
|Point2.y|                               EQU    0x2      ;  short
; End of Structure Point2

; Structure, __fpos_t_struct , Size 0x10 bytes, from C:\Program Files\DS-5\bin\..\include\stdio.h
|__fpos_t_struct.__pos|                  EQU    0        ;  unsigned long long
|__fpos_t_struct.__mbstate|              EQU    0x8      ;  anonymous
|__fpos_t_struct.__mbstate.__state1|     EQU    0x8      ;  unsigned int
|__fpos_t_struct.__mbstate.__state2|     EQU    0xc      ;  unsigned int
; End of Structure __fpos_t_struct

END
```

Comment: [Is there a way?](http://cdn.gifbay.com/2012/11/is_such_a_thing_even_possible-9397.gif)

Comment: Would have to see example of what you're doing, odds are threading won't help because stock Python has the GIL interpreter to contend with at the very least. So unless you have something doing async C calls on the backend with a queue.. probably out of luck. You might be able to refactor it into a map/reduce problem but without example code.. tough luck joe!

Comment: It would be better to insert a sample of the file into the question. External links are fragile and sometimes difficult to access.

Comment: The GIL only hurts CPU-bound workloads.  I/O-bound workloads work fine.  CPU-and-I/O-bound workloads do have problems with the GIL.

Comment: You probably should profile your code.  If it appears CPU-bound, Pypy might help quite a bit, as might numba or Cython.  If it's I/O bound, stick with CPython, and consider something like mmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably be better off optimizing your parser code, or writing it in a different language.

In the standard Python implementation ("CPython"), the only way to effectively multiprocess is to use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, which relies on using multiple unix processes rather than threads (threading isn't really possible for compute-bound tasks because of the global interpreter lock). You can use shared-memory objects and even shared dictionaries (see [Managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)) but basically **inter-process communication is very costly**, and will soon consume the advantage of multitasking.

If your individual threads don't require global information about the structures during the parse, they could each create their own dictionary, and then you could merge all the dictionaries at the end. It's easy enough to send a (picklable) Python object from one process to another, but consider the following: your task it to parse a textual representation and create an internal representation. Pickling and unpickling an object consists of taking an internal representation, producing a string from it, and then parsing the string at the other end of the communications channel. In other words, **your parsing task simply generates another parsing task**, with some additional overhead for serialization. That's unlikely to be much of a win except that the unpickler may well be a faster parser than you have written. Which brings us back to optimizing the parser.

The one part of the parallelization problem which is usually straight-forward is splitting the tasks between processes. Assuming that the chunks to be parsed (`start:finish`) are not too huge -- that is, that your 410k lines consists of, say, several thousand such subtasks -- then there is a simple strategy:

1. Find the size of the file, and divide it by the number of tasks (See below.)
2. Give each task a byte range: `[task_number * task_size, task_number * task_size)`.
3. Each task does the following:

   1. Open the file (so each task has its own file descriptor)
   2. Seek to the start byte position
   3. Read and discard until the end of a line
   4. Read lines, discarding them until the start of a section is found.
   5. Loop:

      1. Parse a section.
      2. Read until the first line of the start of the next section.
      3. If the position of the first character in the start line is within the
         range, continue the loop.
   6. Report the result

---

The problem with this simple algorithm is that it assumes that the cost of a parse is strictly proportional to the number of characters parsed and that all threads will execute at the same speed. Since neither of these assumptions is likely, it is quite possible that some threads will finish considerably before others, and will then just spin their wheels waiting for more work.

This can be avoided by splitting the file into smaller pieces and having each thread get the next available piece when it finishes the one it is working on. (Of course, you have to coordinate the work queue, but that's only one synchronization per chunk of work, which is not a lot of overhead.) However, I didn't recommend this above because the input file is not so huge that it can be divided into really small pieces. Since the actual start and end of work need to be found with an actual scan, there is **some overhead associated with every chunk of work** and the more chunks there are, the more overhead. If the chunks are small enough, there will be some with no actual work at all. Getting the tuning parameters right requires more knowledge about the size of the work units than is revealed by the question.

Comment: That's what I was planning on doing. I was also thinking about diving by `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` and assigning a process to parse each of the byte ranges. Would that be any better or does python multiprocessing require too much overhead for something as simple as parsing?

Comment: @ZWiki: I thought I was clear in my answer that python multiprocessing imposes more overhead than an efficient parse. I'll go back and emphasize the words.

Comment: Ah, I missed part of the comment at the bottom. Yea, the main problem is these "sections" aren't easily dividable. For instance even splitting it into 8 sections and producing 50k lines for a process/thread wouldn't be that simple as the sections would need to land on a `; Structure...` boundary. I just wasn't sure if a process would be more overhead than it's worth relative to how long mine takes now. Unfortunately this is the only language that it can be written in. I'm not sure how much more efficient I can make it, part of it is just the huge file, which is why I thought split it

Comment: @ZWiki: The whole point of the algorithm I present is that it deals with the fact that the precise location of `; Structure` boundaries is not known. It does mean that a small (or not so small, depending on the size of a `; Structure` section) amount of the file is read twice, but in practice that overhead is not nearly as great as the rest of the interprocess overhead. If Python could multitask, the problem would be much simpler, but it can't. So that leaves needing to optimize. I don't know what your parse consists of, but 1.4 seconds to do 400k lines seems a bit high to me.